# Send javascript array to SQL then get info back to the HTML

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a javascript array which stores seat numbers (in a cinema), which are selected by the user via clicking and added to the array each time using a function. I want the page to show the total cost of these seats, which means accessing an sql table inside some php.

So I have e.g. seatNumbers = ["a1", "d6", "e3"] and three sql query like 'select cost from seat where seat_number='a1';'. The function that adds to the array on clicking a seat and prints the seats is something like:

```
var seatArray = [];
function addSeat(seat) {
seatArray.push(seat);
  document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML="Seats : ";

  for (x in arraytest) {
  document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML+=arraytest[x];
  document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML+=" ";
  }
```

}

And I want to show the total cost in the HTML.

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to achieve is possible? What would be the general method and would I need to load a new page instead? And if it's not possible, what would be a better way to go about this?

Comment: either you preload all the values, or make an xmlhttprequest on request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and to answer it, quite some stuff needs to be known and used.

What you want is very possible though. In fact, there are technologies that in their core focus on providing solutions to problems like yours! What you need is some solid info (and possibly experience with) AJAX and maybe even REST. By using AJAX your page wont have to reload, and in your situation AJAX is probably the best choice anyway.

To point you in the right direction: [AJAX javascript W3Schools Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and [PHP AJAX W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Then, use jQuery to make it all a LOT easier: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) (i'd go for 1.x)

You'll have to create an API that accepts an HTTP (preferably GET) request and returns the cost for the seat that you refer to in your URL like (more REST like, should return a whole seat object with price included): `/seat/200`, or (not REST like)`/seat/cost/200`).

Your choice if you want to follow (if you haven't read up on it, possibly confusing) REST rules. In your situation i'd just begin with some good old AJAX, it just works and is even better suited for stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I'm going to have to do quite a bit of reading!

Comment: Yes, but it'll be worth your while :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX. Try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

Covert Your array with seats on JSON string and send it by AJAX to page which check the whole price. Then, You can update Your HTML code with total cost.

```
var json_data = '{...}';

$.ajax({
    url: "total_cost.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { json: json_data },
    success: function(response) {
        // .. on success
        var json_response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var cost = json_response.total_cost;
    }
});
```